# How can I compare if two dates in JS are equal?

Tags: javascript

I have two dates in a form:

```
var date = Wed Oct 07 2015 19:48:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time);

var dateOne = new Date(date);
var dateTwo = new Date();

if (dateOne == dateTwo )
    alert ("equals");
else{
    alert("not equal");
}
```

and even if I set up the date on client's site to `Wed Oct 07 2015 19:48:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)` I'm still getting `not equal`...

Even when I do this:

```
var data1 = new Date();
var data2 = new Date();



if (data1 == data2)
    alert ("equals");
else{
    alert("not equal");
}
```

The `not equal` appears again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you compare objects with `==`, it checks to see if they are the *same object*, not just the same value.

You can try to get the difference between them to see if it's 0:

```
if (data1-data2 === 0)
    alert ("equals");
else{
    alert("not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably they differ in miliseconds. Trim miliseconds before comparing if you don't need that precision.

> `date1.setMilliseconds(0);`
>   `date2.setMilliseconds(0);`

Comment: and in that case how can I trim them for those milliseconds? I'm only interested in comparing date and time with a precision for seconds...

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call Date() you get a different date because time is passing. If you set date2 = date1, only then will they be equal. The date has a millisecond component.